# forgot the moodle admin password of my local moodle server

Tags: passwords, admin, moodle, forgot-password, moodle-api

**forgot the moodle admin password of my local moodle`your text` server**
i am using the version 4.1 moodle
i know the username but unfortunetly forgot the password my local moodle server.
i have tried to forgot the password i havent give the smtp address so i cant recieve the mail of reset password

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coVlb.png)

login to moodle server but
i have forgot the passwqord so i am not able to login

Answer (score 2):

You can reset the password from the command line

```
php admin/cli/reset_password.php --username=admin --password=newpassword
```

Comment: Its not working i have tried but not worked

Comment: Try without the parameters, it will prompt you for the name and password `php admin/cli/reset_password.php` - if it still doesn't work, then double check `config.php` to make sure you are using the correct url and database.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more hacky approach that works provided you have access to the database.

For context, Moodle uses the PHP function [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) to generate a password hash for users. The basic idea is that you want to use this function in a plain PHP file outside of Moodle to output a password hash of a new password. This hash is then manually saved in the *password* field in your `mdl_user` table using your database client and your new password used to login to the site.

PHP File:

```
<?php
echo password_hash("new_password", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Example output of password_hash:

`$2y$10$NCC4PVZ1kTRg4bT21yEl2eUVWMf3lkbYtczTn8vB53qNwTqtN9jwS`

Answer (score 0):

It happens to the best of us, me included, what I did was the following:

1. Access Moodle's DB
2. Locate the user table
3. Go to the "username" column
4. Find the "admin" user
5. Use php's password_hash function
6. Update the password in your DB
7. Most importantly save your changes

Now you should be able to access your local Moodle installation using the new password.

Always keep records of your passwords to avoid tiresome issues like this one.